# Pandas groupby operations

Tags: pandas, group-by

Having a certain df:

```
Start  End   N   Count  Avg 
1      abc1  10    2    .5
1      abc2  10    2    .5
1      xyz1  10    2    .5
1      xyz2  10    2    .5  
1      ijk1  10    2    .5
2      abc1  12    3    .4
2      xyz1  12    1    .1
2      xyz2  12    1    .4
2      ijk1  12    6    .5 
2      ijk2  12    1    .7
```

My goal is to group all the xyz... into 1 group and ijk in 1 group.  Then sum the Count and take average of Avg.

```
Start  End   N   Count  Avg 
1      abc1  10    2    .5
1      abc2  10    2    .5
1      xyz   10    4    .5
1      ijk   10    2    .5
2      abc1  12    3    .4
2      xyz   12    2    .25
2      ijk   12    7    .6
```

I have tried df.groupby().agg(sum) but I have 2 problems with this:

I don't want to group abc.. just anything with ijk and xyz

I want to control the sum and average separately depends on the field's name

Any thought? Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to groupby the string part of the column End and use agg

```
df[df['End'].str.contains('ijk|xyz')]\
.groupby(['Start', df['End'].str.extract('([A-Za-z]+)', expand = False)])\
.agg({'Count': 'sum', 'Avg': 'mean'})

             Count  Avg
Start   End     
1       ijk  2      0.50
        xyz  4      0.50
2       ijk  7      0.60
        xyz  2      0.25
```

Note: You can simplify the code to extract string from the column End if there is only one number that needs to be excluded. Something like,

```
df[df['End'].str.contains('ijk|xyz')]\
.groupby(['Start', df['End'].str[:-1]])\
.agg({'Count': 'sum', 'Avg': 'mean'})
```

Resetting index

```
df[df['End'].str.contains('ijk|xyz')]\
```

.groupby(['Start', df['End'].str[:-1]])\
.agg({'Count': 'sum', 'Avg': 'mean'}).reset_index()

```
    Start   End Count   Avg
0   1       ijk 2   0.50
1   1       xyz 4   0.50
2   2       ijk 7   0.60
3   2       xyz 2   0.25
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  How can I reset all the index in this case?  Would it just be df.reset_index? Because I would need to concat this with the original df

Comment: Yes, reset_index would work best for resetting the index

Comment: Can you check again? Its working fine here. I just updated the answer